# How do we make this JS ES6+ Higher Order Function clean?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, higher-order-functions

Currently learning JS ES6+ syntax and am doing an exercise on finding the average salary of developers vs average salary of non-developers. The code is working but from my understanding, clean code is having a function doing only 1 task.Currently, averagePay has 3 tasks.

Is there a way to feed these 3 tasks as unnamed functions into averagePay using arrow method, keeping them all wrapped inside one single averagePay. I do not wish to create too many functions on the outside.

Apologies if I am using the wrong terms or causing even more confusion.
Am still learning Higher Order Functions and trying to wrap my head around multiple layers of functions within function within functions.

Thank you for your kind help.

```js
const datasetEmployee = [
    {
        name: 'Person1',
        job: 'developer',
        salary: 1000
    },
    {
        name: 'Person2',
        job: 'developer',
        salary: 2000
    },
    {
        name: 'Person3',
        job: 'Job3',
        salary: 3000
    }
];


const averagePay = (dataFiltered) => {

    const filteredSalary = dataFiltered.map( (each) => each.salary);
    const sumSalary = filteredSalary.reduce((acc,curr) => acc+curr, 0);
    return sumSalary/filteredSalary.length;
}

const isDev = datasetEmployee.filter( (each) => each.job === 'developer');
const isNotDev = datasetEmployee.filter( (each) => each.job !== 'developer');


console.log(averagePay(isDev));
console.log(averagePay(isNotDev));
```

strong text

Comment: Looks quite reasonable to me

Comment: Note that questions about improving working code should be asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thank you for your kind and quick help, everyone. Will also take note to post future working codes on Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

You can define functions inside the `averagePay` function and use those.

```
const averagePay = (dataFiltered) => {
    const getSalaries = arr => arr.map(({salary}) => salary),
          getSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
    return getSum(getSalaries(dataFiltered)) / dataFiltered.length;
}
```

```js
const datasetEmployee = [
    {
        name: 'Person1',
        job: 'developer',
        salary: 1000
    },
    {
        name: 'Person2',
        job: 'developer',
        salary: 2000
    },
    {
        name: 'Person3',
        job: 'Job3',
        salary: 3000
    }
];


const averagePay = (dataFiltered) => {
    const getSalaries = arr => arr.map(({salary}) => salary),
          getSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
    return getSum(getSalaries(dataFiltered)) / dataFiltered.length;
}

const isDev = datasetEmployee.filter( (each) => each.job === 'developer');
const isNotDev = datasetEmployee.filter( (each) => each.job !== 'developer');


console.log(averagePay(isDev));
console.log(averagePay(isNotDev));
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to change is only naming maybe, but otherwise it is good enough. Average pay is doing one thing - calculating the pay average. Otherwise it would have to receive 2 parameters and divide them, which is basically useless.

```
const averagePay = (employees) => {
    const numberOfEmployees = employees.length;
    const sumOfSalaries = employees.map(employee => employee.salary)
        .reduce((sum, salary) => sum + salary, 0);

    return sumOfSalaries / numberOfWorkers ;
}

const developers = datasetEmployee.filter(employee  => employee .job === 'developer');
const nonDevelopers = datasetEmployee.filter(employee => employee.job !== 'developer');
```

you could alternatively do this:

```
const sumSalaries = (employees) => {
    return employees.map(employee => employee.salary)
        .reduce((sum, salary) => sum + salary, 0)
}

const averagePay = (employees) => {
    const numberOfEmployees = employees.length;

    return sumSalaries(employees) / numberOfWorkers ;
}
```

But I don't see much improvement other than the possibility for the reuse of the sum function.